# Explorer.exe stops working in Windows Server 2008

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-explorer, windows-server-2008

When we are working on the server via remote desktop, the start menu disappears. We are not able to continue working.  We figured out that `explorer.exe` stops working.

Is there any way to restart `explorer.exe` (and get back the start menu) via the command prompt?  We are using Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd>, this should bring up the Task Manager. From there, you can access the `File`->`Run` menu option, type `explorer` and press <kbd>OK</kbd>, which should return your toolbar and menus.

Comment: Thank you!  I don't use Windows myself, just tech-support for it... often I know WHAT I want, but not what it's named/called.  I appreciate your edit.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to execute the explorer.exe again via command prompt?

Yup, If you just need to relaunch the `explorer` via `CMD` then type in `"explorer.exe"` or just `"explorer"` and it will launch the explorer again. You can also do it via Task Manager's New task option and typing the same thing.

You said that you want Start Menu back, this **may or may not** bring the start menu back as there can be other issues as well. You asked about how to relaunch the explorer so here is the answer.

Comment: Sorry for late reply guys. I tried both, but it cant works. It simply opens the explorer window. Start menu still not working :(

Comment: Hey, I said the same thing that @lornix said.

Comment: Ya But ctrl+Alt+del is not working in that server. Instead of that ctrl+shift+esc only working. That's why i selected as correct answer dude.

Comment: I din't EVER mentioned ctrl+alt+del and I included the Task Manager process (Assuming you know how to launch the Task Manager) Also you asked How to launch it via CMD, thats my main answer.